# gradle is getting installed multiple times and its ends up with failure

Tags: gradle

when I open a new project on android studio it stuck at the Gradle installation process.
android studio installs the Gradle plugin multiple times as you can see from the build window

```
    Download https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip finished, took 1 m 53 s 231 ms (115.85 MB)
    Download https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip finished, took 4 m 29 s 699 ms (115.85 MB)
```

I don't know what could cause the problem, I tried to create a new project but the same problem

Answer (score 0):

you can find gradle-wrapper-properties both files. delete one and synk project.

or clean project/rebuild project
or invalidate cache and restart

#android_studio

Answer (score -1):

Try updating android studio to the newer version
Hopefully, it should solve the issue.